# subprojects versus modules angular 7

Tags: angular

I have an admin app where I control configurations for different apps. Right now each admin app is deployed as an individual app. I am planning to collate all admin apps as one app and use routing on top of it. I was thinking to make each as a module and use it. I stumbled upon projects.sub-projects concept in Angular. Not sure if I can use it for my use case i.e. create different admin apps ad sub-apps and map them using routing.

Answer (score 1):

**Converting the apps into modules**

How about creating libraries in Angular using ng-packagr.For more information on creating libraries in angular

[https://blog.angulartraining.com/create-your-own-libraries-with-angular-cli-7b434600bbb7](https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5)

https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5

Several other documents are available in creating a library.This may help you converting the apps into modules.